# How can I get the index of a custom-object-element in a List<customClass> using an object property?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I have a custom Class 'Student' that has two properties 'name' & 'age'.
In my main method, I've created a List of this custom class, List, and added 4 Student objects to the List.
My question is, how can I get the index of one of the objects using any of the object's propertied?

For example how can I get the index of Student('Dido', 18)?

```dart
void main() {
  List<Student> studentsList = [];
  studentsList.add(Student('Jack', 16));
  studentsList.add(Student('Tamer', 17));
  studentsList.add(Student('Dido', 18));
  studentsList.add(Student('Lili', 15));    
}

class Student{
  String name;
  int age;  
  Student(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/List/indexOf.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use indexWhere 
the following code has tested in Dardpad 
full code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';

class Student{
  String name;
  int age;  
  Student(this.name, this.age);
} 

main()  {  

  List<Student> studentsList = [];

  studentsList.add(Student('Jack', 16));
  studentsList.add(Student('Tamer', 17));
  studentsList.add(Student('Dido', 18));
  studentsList.add(Student('Lili', 15));

  int index = studentsList.indexWhere((st) => st.name=='Dido' && st.age==18); 
  print(index);

}
```